VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode OR the EVM version used by the selected environment is not compatible
I am deploying solidity contract at remix I am getting the above error
below is my solidity code
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.6.12 <0.9.0;

contract SupplyChain {
    
    event Added(uint256 index);
    
    struct State {
        string description;
        address person;
    }
    
    struct Product {
        address creator;
        string productName;
        uint256 productId;
        string date;
        uint256 totalStates;
        mapping (uint256 => State) positions;
    }
    
    mapping(uint => Product) allProducts;
    uint256 items=0;
    
    function concat(string memory _a, string memory _b) public pure returns (string memory){
        bytes memory bytes_a = bytes(_a);
        bytes memory bytes_b = bytes(_b);
        string memory length_ab = new string(bytes_a.length + bytes_b.length);
        bytes memory bytes_c = bytes(length_ab);
        uint k = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < bytes_a.length; i++) bytes_c[k++] = bytes_a[i];
        for (uint i = 0; i < bytes_b.length; i++) bytes_c[k++] = bytes_b[i];
        return string(bytes_c);
    }
    
    function newItem(string memory _text, string memory _date) public returns (bool) {
    Product storage newProduct = allProducts[items];
    newProduct.creator = msg.sender;
    newProduct.productName = _text;
    newProduct.productId = items;
    newProduct.date = _date;
    newProduct.totalStates = 0;

    items++;

    emit Added(items-1);
    return true;
}

    
    function addState(uint _productId, string memory info) public returns (string memory) {
        require(_productId < items, "Invalid Product ID");
        
        State memory newState;
        newState.person = msg.sender;
        newState.description = info;
        
        allProducts[_productId].positions[allProducts[_productId].totalStates] = newState;
        allProducts[_productId].totalStates++;
        
        return info;
    }
    
    function searchProduct(uint _productId) public view returns (string memory) {
        require(_productId < items, "Invalid Product ID");
        
        string memory output = "Product Name: ";
        output = concat(output, allProducts[_productId].productName);
        output = concat(output, "<br>Manufacture Date: ");
        output = concat(output, allProducts[_productId].date);
        
        for (uint256 j = 0; j < allProducts[_productId].totalStates; j++) {
            output = concat(output, allProducts[_productId].positions[j].description);
        }
        return output;
    }
}


I tried to deply the smart contract with injected Web3 VM but I am getting warning as
"Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode OR the EVM version used by the selected environment is not compatible with the compiler "
Error message as
creation of SupplyChain pending...
creation of SupplyChain errored: Error occurred: Internal JSON-RPC error..
Internal JSON-RPC error.
Debug the transaction to get more information.

Try using solidity 0.8.19 or lower. See here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/150281/invalid-opcode-opcode-0x5f-not-defined
